# extracting first line from file using awk command

Tags: unix, awk

I've been going through an online `UNIX` course and have come across this question which I'm stuck on. Would appreciate any help!

> You are provided with a set of files each one of which contains personal details about an individual. Each file is laid out in the following format, with one file per individual:
>
> ```
> name:Niko Tanaka 
> age:41 
> occupation:Doctor
> ```

I know the answer has to be in the form:

```
n=$(awk -F: '   /   /{print }'  filename)
```

Comment: `awk NR==1`, or do you have to only print the name? `awk -F: 'NR==1{print $2}'`

Comment: And in case the file is very big, it can be good to do `awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}'` so the file is not read any more after the first line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
n=$(awk -F: '/name/{print $2}' infile)
```

Whatever is inside of `/ /` are regular expressions. In this case you just want to match on the line that contains 'name'.